# $de^{-x^2}$ as an integration variable

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

I found this expression:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=-\int_0^\infty x de^{-x^2}$$

It's the first time I see an integration variable like $de^{-x^2}$. It is even legit to use it? What rule I have to follow to transform the first integral to the second?

Comment: That expression is not correct.

Comment: @MarkViola is right thats not correct

Comment: The RHS is a legitimate expression when you view it as a [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral). For practical purposes, you can view an expression of the form $\int f dg$ as a short hand of $\int f \frac{dg}{dx} dx$. For the equality at hand, you can derive it using integration by part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that by the chain rule :
$$\frac {de^{-x^2}}{dx}=e^{-x^2}(-2x)$$
Multiply by $dx$
$$de^{-x^2}=-2xe^{-x^2}dx$$
$$\int de^{-x^2}=-2\int xe^{-x^2}dx$$
Therefore :
$$\int e^{-x^2}dx=- \frac 12\int \frac {d(e^{-x^2})}{x}$$
Not what you have

Answer (score 1):

You could consider this to be an almost chain rule like analog to integration. Consider,

$\,\frac{de^{-x^2}}{dx} = -2xe^{-x^2}$

so , $\,de^{-x^2} = -2xe^{-x^2} {dx} $

So the integral becomes, $\,-\large{\int_0^\infty} x.-2xe^{-x^2} {dx} $

It can now be integrated easily.

Answer (score 1):

This can be viewed at least a couple of different ways.

1. As a [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral).
2. As the substitution $u=e^{-x^2}$ giving $-\int_0^\infty x\,\mathrm{d}e^{-x^2}=-\int_1^0\sqrt{-\log(u)}\,\mathrm{d}u$

The rule to get from the first to the second is [Integration by Parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts).